# Java Scanner hasNext() string regex validation

Tags: java, regex, string, expression

I'm trying to get a Java regular expression to work to try and validate a user input using the `Scanner` `System.in` function. What I am trying to validate is a user input that can only contain letters as input, and can contain more than one word. If I type in for example ("Test1") It will throw up a message, warning that I must enter only letters, and prompt to enter it in again, however if I was to type in ("Test 1"), then it would pass through my regex, it seems to be that the space is causing this problem, but adding a space in my regex has not solved my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the section of my code that is having the issues:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the your name: ");

while(!input.hasNext("[a-zA-Z]+")){

    System.out.println("Your name must consist of only letters");
    input.nextLine();

}

String name = input.nextLine();
```

This may be clearly wrong to someone, but I am new to Java and regex and have been trying to find out all day whats been going wrong with no success.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try `^[a-zA-Z_ ]*$` It isn't perfect by any means, but it's simple enough for a newbie to understand.

Comment: Maybe `^[a-zA-Z_ ]+$` so empty strings are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add a space inside the `[]`. I would also suggest using `^` (to state it must be the start of the string) and `$` (for the end of the string):

```
^[a-zA-Z ]+$
```

You can also use `\s` to select all whitespace, like <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Your full code:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the your name: ");

while(!input.hasNext("^[a-zA-Z ]+$")){
    System.out.println("Your name must consist of only letters");
    input.nextLine();
}

String name = input.nextLine();
```

If you want to allow symbols like `*`, so everything **but** numbers. you could use `\d+`. If it matches, then print out the error (you wil need to remove the `!` in your `while` statement)

Comment: I was going to propose the same answer, but it wouldn't work.. I tested this same code with `John Doe` and it would renter the loop, and I can't figure out why..

Comment: I have the same issue as Maljam, I have been trying this all day, it just does not seem to validate the input if a space is present. Will only work on a string like "Test1" and not "Test 1", even with the added space in the []. Thanks for the suggestion though Druzion!

Comment: @ChocolateDogBone Did you try with `\s`?

Comment: @Druzion, Yeah I tried with \\s in my regex too, with no success, my solution below posted is how I am getting around this issue now!

Answer (score 0):

`hasNext(pattern)` will match the next **complete token** against the Regex pattern.
according to this method documentation `getCompleteTokenInBuffer(Pattern pattern)` from `Scanner`

> A token is complete if surrounded by delims; a partial token is prefixed by delims but not postfixed by them.

The problem is that the default delimiter in `Scanner` is whitespace, because of that only the string before the whitespace will be tested against the pattern.

### Solution

`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\R");`

Calling `hasNext(pattern)` on the above scanner will match the pattern against the whole line.

**NOTE** The pattern should never match the delimiter, in this case, the newline character.